# Intuition behind $o$ and $O$ notation

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, asymptotics

This question has arleady been asked, but I'm not satisfied with answers given there.

I've been struggling for some time with understand the true meaning and inuition behind of $o$ and $O$ notation.

Definitions that I've been given are following:

$D1$. $f=O(g)$ when $x \to x_0$, if there is neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ and constant $c>0$, such that:
  $$|f(x)| \leq c|g(x)|$$ when $x \in U$.

$D2$. $f=o(g)$ when $x \to x_0$, if there is neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$, such that: $$f(x)=\epsilon(x)g(x)$$
when $x \in U$, where $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal function when $x \to x_0$.

I don't really understand the $O$ notation.

For when we are talking about $o$ notation, I think that this several cases are the most important ones, and rest is not really applicable (?).
If $g$ is infinitesimal too, then so is $f$, and we can say that $f$ tends to zero faster than $g$.
But if $g,f \to +-\infty$, then $g$ tends to $+-\infty$ faster then $f$.

But what if $g,f$ are not from the cases above ?
What if they don't have limit when $x \to x_0$ ?
And does it have to be explained in terms of $tends to$ ?
Someone sometime said to me, not really precise,that it has sommeting to do with $growth$, but I can't see how to apply that to this separate cases that I listed.

Comment: "If $g$ is infinitesimal too, then so is $f$, and we can say that $g$ tends to zero faster than $f$. But if $g,f \to +-\infty$, then $f$ tends to $+-\infty$ faster then $g$." Please edit here; you've confused $f$ with $g$ .

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Comment: Assuming $f,g$ are real-valued, $f=O(g)$ means that $f/g$ stays bounded near $x_0$. This might apply when $f$ and $g$ are both getting small, or both getting large, or maybe they're both doing neither, it doesn't matter. (Technically you might even have $f$ getting small and $g$ getting large, but in this case the statement is so imprecise that it's probably not useful).

Comment: $f=o(g)$ means that $f/g \to 0$ as $x \to x_0$. This requires that either $f$ is getting small or $g$ is getting large, but again it could happen that both are getting small, or both are getting large, or just $f$ is getting small, or just $g$ is getting large.

Comment: '$f=O(g)$ means that $f/g$ stays bounded near $x_0$' - this clears it up a bit.

Comment: @Ian So you agree that definitions are too broad and we define them like that just for the sake of formality, because we are using them just in some special cases ?

Comment: So, $O$ and $o$ actually just tells you information of the quotient $f/g$ around a point. One tells you is bounded, the other tells you something stronger, that this indeed arbitrarily small as you shrink your neighborhood.

Comment: They're not too broad. They can create some meaninglessly imprecise statements, but that's our fault, not the notation's fault. However, it is true that we usually use these notations when either $g$ is a constant, or $f,g$ are both getting small, or $f,g$ are both getting large. The former is of course easily read off from the notation, but distinguishing between the latter two isn't something the notation helps you with. In practice that's not really a defect, because it's usually obvious which one you're in based on context.

Comment: (Cont.)  (For example, in computer science, it's almost never the "getting small" case.)